# CounterStrike: Source stuttering on MacBook Pro

Tags: technical-issues, macos, counter-strike-source

My friend is having some problems with CS:S on his MacBook Pro:

> if you stand still its like 100+ fps, if you fire there is a millisecond stutter, any fighting and it's completely unplayable
>
> i put cl_showfps 1 and its usually 100odd and green, then it flicks to red (<20fps) for a millisecond

His MacBook Pro is from early 2011 which I believe has dedicated graphics, either way I would have thought such an old game would run okay on his machine?

Thanks

Comment: If it happens when he fires it could also be soundcard related, just a thought. Sound quality can slow the game down as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to update both your game and graphics drivers to the latest version to check if this problem has been fixed, first.

There could be many reasons for this problem, namely

**Overheating:** Microstuttering is a very common symptom of overheating. Does the stutter happen as soon as he starts the game or after playing for sometime? Check the CPU and GPU temperatures before starting the game and after the stuttering starts and check how hot the system is running.

**Configuration:** Another solution you can try is one linked on the official Steam for MAC forums [HERE](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1324704)

Edit or create `autoexec.cfg` located in `users/your username/library/application support/steam/steamapps/your steam account name/counter-strike source/cstrike/cfg` to match the following:

```
//_Set Netcode vars_
cl_cmdrate "66"
cl_interp "0.033" //try "0.0151515" if that is laggy for you.
cl_interp_ratio "1" 
cl_updaterate "66"
rate "25000" // you can try higher, I have mine set to 100000 (probably unnecessary but alwell it is smooth. )
fps_max "60"
```

Comment: Many thanks Vinay, I will recommend that he checks his autoexec.cfg file - I don't believe it is overheating although I will mention that to him as well!

Answer (score 1):

Note that although CSS is an old game (2004), the graphics have been upgraded substantially over the years. Especially the last big update somewhere in 2010 made the game much more hardware intensive, it switched to using the Team Fortress 2 version of the source engine. I currently use an AMD X2 5000+, 4GB ram, and an HD 4770, which is much more graphics power than the MacBook 2011 can muster. With this setup I get good performance, 100+ to 40+ at very busy moments. So I am not really surprised at the lack of performance of CSS on your friends macbook.